# Safe way to replace strings in HTML with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

Suppose that one has:

- an element object `element`.
- a regular expression or a simple string `pattern`.
- a string `replacement` (this can be a simple string or one with replacement tokens).

In JavaScript, without invoking jQuery or a JavaScript library, how can one safely replace all of the occurrences of `pattern` with `replacement` in the child text nodes of `element`? How can one achieve this if `replacement` also contains markup instead of text that will be escaped if it contains less-than signs or greater-than signs? The problem with using `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(pattern, replacement)` is that it can potentially break markup. So, using that to replace a hyperlink's displayed text could change the address the hyperlink points to.

The answer can contain can contain two solutions: one that replaces text with text (i.e., "<" in `replacement` would be treated as `&lt;`) and one that replaces text with literal of the string (i.e., `<br/>` in `replacement` would be treated as `<br/>` instead of `&lt;br/&gt;`). Alternatively, the answer may contain only one solution that, like the second solution in the first option, treats `<` and `>` as `<` and `>`, respectively.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Do a search on `childNodes` and how to determine which ones are text nodes (hint: `nodeType`).

Comment: Do not attempt to parse HTML with a regular expression, see [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

I would change all of the `<` and `>`s first then you can check for `br`. You need to use the `g` flag at the end of your expressions to make them greedy. I put optional spaces and a forward slash option in there too. Have fun... and try to make your JavaScript XHTML friendly so it's transportable.

```js
// external.js
var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, E, stripMost; // keeping vars above the onload allows for use on other pages - change pre to different var name if using technique on another page
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // execute previous onload if exists
  
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
stripMost = function(inputString){
  return inputString.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/&lt;\s*br\s*\/?s*&gt;/g, '<br />');
}
var so = E('so'); // works like document.getElementById('so')
so.onclick = function(){
  E('out').innerHTML = stripMost(E('in').value);
}

}
```

```css
/* external.css */
#in{
  width:200px; height:25px; border:1px solid #000;
}
#so{
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='in' /> <input type='button' id='so' value='show output' />
  <div id='out'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not attempt to parse HTML with a regular expression, see [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). See mseifert's comment for how to go about it.

Comment: That is the craziest Stack Overflow page I've ever seen. At least it made me laugh. `.innerHTML` and `.value`s are Strings, therefore fine for RegEx's.

Comment: It's an odd question, since it seems to want to arbitrarily decide whether to treat "<" and ">" as parts of tags or plain characters, which indicates some kind of parsing that is more complex than provided by a regular expression.